# wcf service with tcp binding: how to know if a client insert login/password?

Tags: wcf, tcp

Well, in my first version of my service, I have a duplex contract, so I can save the information o a client, such its username name, if it has logged correctly... etc. The goal was only allow to call methods if the client has logged correctly.

However, I need to work with large files, so I decide that my service must use the streamed transfer mode, but if I use streamed as transport mode, I can't use a duplex contract.

So My question is how could I know if I a client is logged or not? I wouldn't like to send in every call the user and password.

Also I would like to use a service per call, for scalability reasons, so I can't save the information from a call to other. or perhaps I could use a static list with all the clients that has been logged?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "simple" way:

1. Create a method on your service which authenticates your user based on user name and password. If the authentication is done with success then generate a token (GUID). Use a high performance external caching system such as CouchBase to store your token.
2. On each client request pass the token into the message headers so that on you service level, using a message inspector you can retrieve it. Once you got it check if same token exists on your external cache. If it does then you can allow the request to continue its trip, if not then throw an exception (fault) to inform the client that wrong credential where used.
3. When you save the token on the cache set up and expiration policy which will be renewed on each successful request.

There is a catch in all this, because you are going to use a per call with out a session, you can't know exactly when your client stops using the service (like the windows application/browser is closed). So your token will reside on the cache for a while (defined by your caching policy).

The "complex" way:

1. Make use of a Security Token Service (STS) 
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804740.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If its TCP binding even if you pass username and password in each request it will be pretty safe if 
protection level is set to EncryptAndSign. If windows authentication mode is set the channel autmatically embeds this information on each request.

```
<security mode = "Transport">
            <transport
               clientCredentialType = "Windows"
               protectionLevel = "EncryptAndSign"
            />
</security>
```